Blazor - why do anything on the 2nd call to OnInitializedAsync()?
This is a follow-on question to my question Why is OnInitializedAsync() called twice?
What I have been doing to date, based on Microsoft's guidance that everything should be requested in the pre-render call, is:

Anything that might be cached I call. If it is not in the cache, the pre-render pass will read it in to the cache. Then the second pass will get it from the cache.
Anything small I first look for in the PersistingComponentStateSubscription. If there, I use that. If not there, I read it, save it in the persisted store, and use it.
For anything else, I only call it if it is not a Pre-Render call (HttpContext is not null).

But thinking about it today, it strikes me that we want to call all initialization in the pre-render pass. And then do nothing on the second pass. Which would be the following:

Read PersistingComponentStateSubscription. If that has a value, return.
Write 'true' to PersistingComponentStateSubscription
Perform all initialization, including reading everything needed from the DB even if that will take 10+ seconds.

Is there any downside to the above? I ask, because why have 2 passes if doing this meets the Microsoft guidance to get everything in the pre-render pass?
The flip approach to the above is to do:

Do all fast initialization.
IfPreRender, return (exit).
Do all slow initialization.

But following that means all the slow initialization will be started a bit later. That will mean it will take longer to fully initialize the page. And as Microsoft's guidance implies that a slow pre-render initialization will not slow down the rendering of the page skeleton, I don't see any advantage to this approach.

I've never liked this either.  It feels like a lot of work to solve a problem that nobody had.  But sometimes these things aren't clear until you try to use a live site on a janky, high-latency wifi connection, and then you go, "Ahhhh.  I get it now."

@Bennyboy1973 So what was the Ahhhh specifically for you in this case? Understanding that will help me use this best. TIA

When I was first starting with Blazor, and still bothered to wonder why Init fired twice, I asked this same question.  I did notice that when using a phone as opposed to my dev system, where latency was an issue, large pages (especially those with massive foreach loops on big data sets) would display the menu and other layout formatting first, and then the data a second or two later.  I realized that if everything rendered only once, I might have stared at a blank screen long enough to annoy customers.

(cont.) I suspect (though I don't know) that if I just made a simple page, then loaded my large dataset in OnAfterRender, it would take longer overall than just letting Blazor do what it wants to do.  But I never would have thought so just working on my Dev system.

I'm assuming we're talking InteractiveServer mode here based on your previous questions.
I think you need to consider what you're doing to determine the best solution.  Do you do a lot of work in Pre-Render creating a load of scoped DI objects in the HttpRequest Context to produce data that you then transfer through the PersistingComponentStateSubscription?
Those sevices in the HttpRequest Context then go out-of-scope and are destroyed.  On doing anything in the page you then almost certainly create the same scoped DI objects within the Blazor Hub Session Context.
Everything is still happening on the server: you're just doing a lot of stuff twice.  And creating a PersistingComponentStateSubscription infrastructure to transfer data between those two contexts.
My approach is minimal activity in pre-render: just create a spinner and complete on the presence of HttpContext.  All the data stuff happens in the Blazor Hub Session.  There's no PersistingComponentStateSubscription infrastructure.

Every time I figure there's a better solution than the approach you propose... it bites me in the ass. So I'll revert to what you suggest. Out of curiosity, why not do everything pre-render (so it starts earlier) and nothing on the second pass?

It's simpler. PersistingComponentStateSubscription adds complexity. Fewer objects being created and destroyed.  I can see the advantages in WASM for a landing page, but not in Server.
